# Ionic 2 how to redirect to a login page when I call a secure url

Tags: ionic2, angular-http-interceptors

I wanted to know how to redirect to a login page when I call a secure url, knowing that you can not inject the navController into a service

I created my extended Http service like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {

  constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); 

    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    if (typeof url === 'string') { 
      if (!options) {
        // let's make option object
        options = {headers: new Headers()};
      }
      options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    } else {
      url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    }
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
  }

  private catchAuthError (self: CustomHttp) {
    return (res: Response) => {
     if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {

     }

      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can use events, in your app.component.ts file:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
```

then be sure to declare an event:

```
public events: Events
```

and from within the component call a function:

```
listenToEvents() {
    this.events.subscribe('user:logout', () => {
      this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
    });
  }
```

and finally in your service you can publish the event:

```
private catchAuthError (self: CustomHttp) {
    return (res: Response) => {
     if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
       this.events.publish('user:logout');
     }

      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
```

Comment: It is clear that the OP does not want to have code for navigation to a Login page wherever he calls a service. Instead he/she wants his custom Http automatically navigate to a login page if not logged in.

Comment: I meant the success callback, I didn't indicate anything about an error

Comment: sorry, I mean the Login page. what you suggest is to have the code for setting the root of navigation in every component that uses this service. This is what the OP is trying to avoid. what OP wants is probably against definition of MVC

Comment: The answer is probably achievable using events. I can remove my down vote if you edit your answer